# How to capture a hardware (baremetal) machine's CPU and Memory via the SoftLayer API

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

For a virtual guest machine there are the following:

Virtual Guest CPU:
https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/softlayer_virtual_guest/getCpuMetricDataByDate

Virtual Guest Memory:
https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/softlayer_virtual_guest/getMemoryMetricDataByDate

But I'm not seeing a way to capture similar CPU and Memory utilization information for a hardware machine.  How can this be done?

I've looked at `SoftLayer_Metric_Tracking_Object/$ID/getMetricDataTypes` but only see metrics for network and rack space.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API will retrieve information just as the portal and vice versa, in this particular case unfortunately that information is not available for BMs just as in the portal, and that you were able to verify this by using SoftLayer_Metric_Tracking_Object::getMetricDataTypes on a BM tracking object Id.

All the response strings returned by method above are the ones that are available (e.g.: network, rack space).